# Calculate the average of Particle Count every 2 hour intervals

Tags: tidyverse, lubridate

I'm currently a beginner in using RStudio and need guidance. I have a data set that includes the year, month, day, hour, minute, second and ParticleCount. I'm trying to figure out how to write the code to help me calculate the average of the Particle Count every 2 hour intervals.

I would really appreciate the guidance and support as I continue to learning RStudio.

[image]

I have tried using rolling averages, but the method uses only the Particle Count Column in which it takes the average for row 1-12, 2-13,3,-14, etc. Instead what I needed to see is the average of rows 1-12, 13-24, 25-36, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a variable the way you wanted, as named `rollavg`.

```
 library(tidyverse)

 df %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  mutate(rollavg = 
           split(ParticleCount, (seq_along(~.)-1) %/% 12) %>% 
           map_dbl(mean))
```

Comment: This helped solve my problem. Thank you so much.